# Redirecting output of a script to a file as a background job does not output anything

Tags: linux, bash

I have a line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log
```

It outputs text to the `mention.log` file.

When I try to run it as background job:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log &
```

it does not output anything to this file.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: If you're running both commands in the same environment/shell and the only difference is the `&` at the end of the background version then I don't see why it wouldn't work **unless** the `bundle` command is expecting to read input from the terminal. Do you get **any** output when you invoke the background version? Does the command complete? What do you see if you run `jobs` in the same shell?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running with the following

```
RAILS_ENV=nohup production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log 2>&1 &
```

I have also added **2>&1 &** so that it will also output **STDERR** into your log file should there be any errors and also **nohup** at the beginning of your line.

Comment: file containts "production: command not found"

Comment: Ah I see. Try adding the nohup before "rake"  as I believe this is the application executed? Also remove exec because we use nohup.

Comment: This time I get "nohup: ignoring input" only

Comment: I have updated my last comment as I think it was incorrect and you wouldn't need to use exec I believe as we use nohup.

Comment: This time I get "Could not find command "nohup""